# how long does ECS cache local images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a really big image which takes a long time to pull

When I start a task on an instance it takes like 15+ mins (i have 2 instances). When I start the task again it takes like 2 mins- because the instance has all the layers.

I would Think ECS just keeps the image cached, but if I wait a day or two and run the task again (same image and tag, no new layers) it takes 15mins again.

Is ECS clearing the cache on instances? I only have two instances and confirmed the instances were not deleted/recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR` is set to. By default, it will pull from remote and use cache only if pull fails.

You would want to set it as `prefer-cached`. This will also prevent image cache from being removed by automated image cleanup. Here's the AWS documentation on this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html#image_pull

Comment: is this possible in the task placement settings or only possible by editing the ECS service config on all the nodes?

Comment: As of now, this is only possible by editing the ECS agent configuration (not service config) on nodes.

Comment: How do I confirm what the current setting is? ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR is currently not set but is there a way to confirm what the current cache setting is?

Comment: If it’s not set, then it’s ‘default’. Meaning it’ll pull every time, and use cache only if pull fails.